# Confused with how the 'open' function works in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say i had the code:

```
 file = open('items.txt', 'r')
 print(file.read())
```

This is fine and just prints the entire text file, yet with this:

```
 file = open('items.txt', 'r')
 for line in file:
     print(line)
 print(file.read())
```

So it will run the for loop just fine and print line, yet the last line wont do anything. With the second code, it should print the entire file twice, yet it only prints it once. Could someone explain why?

Comment: Once you've read the file, _there's nothing more to read_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you finished up reading file in your for loop, your cursor is set to the end of the file.

Try this for example:

```
file = open('items.txt', 'r')
 for line in file:
     print(line)

file.seek(0, 0)
print(file.read())
```

It is going to print the whole file twice this time since we set cursor to beginning of the file.

Answer (score 2):

> With the second code, it should print the entire file twice, yet it
>   only prints it once

It only prints the file once because the for loop will read through the entire file. `file` essentially references a position in the file which will change as you go through the file. So, when you have iterated through all of the contents, `file` references the end of the file. If you try to read all of the contents (using `file.read()`) after having iterated through the file, you receive nothing because you're already at the end.

You'll have the same behavior if you do

```
file = open('items.txt', 'r')
print(file.read())
print(file.read())
```

You can navigate to the beginning of the file using `file.seek(0, 0)`.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects.

Comment: The question is tagged [python-3.x], `file` is not a builtin name in python3

Comment: @AnthonySottile Yes, I just realized that now – edited accordingly! It's also not a built-in for Python 2 either, so not sure why I thought it was.